# Dapper - Map result set with unknown number of columns to object with array property

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, dapper

I am using Dapper to map objects coming out of a SQL Server database to C# classes. One of the stored procedures I need to pull results from can have a variable number of columns depending on the context. This result set will always have a primary key column, and then 0 to 30 additional columns that will all be of the same data type.

The result set columns are basically like this:

```
CustomerID | Email1 | Email2 | Email3 | ...
```

Where the number of `Email*` columns depends on the highest number of email addresses on file for a customer in the query.

The natural way to capture this in C# is with a class like this:

```
class Customer {
    int ID { get; set; }
    string[] EmailAddresses { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to use Dapper to map my result set to an object like this?

Answer (score 6):

It is possible if you do a bit of magic via `dynamic`.

```
var user = connection.Query("spGetUser", commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure)
        .Select(x =>
        {
            var result = new Customer { ID = x.Id };
            foreach (var element in x)
            {
                if (element.Key.Contains("Email"))
                    result.EmailAddresses.Add(element.Value.ToString());
            }
            return result;
        }).FirstOrDefault();

public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<string> EmailAddresses { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

A few key points:

- The array is changed to a list so that we can easily and dynamically add data to it.
- Dynamic will always have a small performance hit in comparison to deserializing directly to a strong type.
- This does not check the type of the data held in the `Value` property, nor does it check that there is actually a value present before calling `.ToString()` on it.

Comment: Thank you.  I don't think the `dynamic` and `List` caveats will cause any issues in my scenario.  I will try this at work tomorrow.

Comment: The List will be perfectly performant in comparison to an array.  The hit from dynamic is small but at least worth noting.

Comment: I think the time saved not manually manipulating `DataTable`s will more than make up for it.

Comment: Yes, I've already moved a lot of the queries with standard result set structures in the project to Dapper and the reduction of clutter and hard-coded column name strings is amazing.

Comment: Absolutely :).  it's a wonderful tool.  The flexibility and power is astounding.

Comment: For a while I was avoiding ORMs all together because I thought it had to involve a jungle of XML config files.

Comment: Well, in that case, welcome to the other side :).  It's a fantastic place to live.